# Batch file to find path of files matching extension, then create new file in same directory

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that will find all files with a `csproj` extension in a large hierarchy of directories.

Wherever I find one, I want to then create a new `SameName.csproj.user` file, and put some hard coded text in it. i.e 'test text'

How can this be done in a batch script?

Comment: This question does not adequately demonstrate that attempts have been made to solve the problem. Please consider adding some code that isn't working right, to narrow down the answer and to prevent the question from looking like a code request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested:

```
@echo off
:: put your dir here
pushd c:\cproj_dir


for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s /a-d *.csproj') do (
  echo test text >"%%~dpfnxf.user"
)
```